# Why Json Object order mixed up in android KITKAT and below versions?

Tags: android, json, android-api-levels

I am trying to send these `JSONbject` to server for login and its working like a charm in android lollipop and marshmallow but when I trying to login in android kitkat and below version then its giving incorrect username and password error because of json order mixup. How can I solve that ?

```
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("USERName", username);
                jsonObject.put("LOGINPASSWORD", password);
                jsonObject.put("IMEINUMBER1", imeino);
                jsonObject.put("Latitude", latitude);
                jsonObject.put("Longitude", longitude);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Below is my `jsonObject` which mixup in Android Kitkat and below versions.

```
{"USERName":"Rahul","Latitude":24.588532515497256,"Longitude":73.7020509167292,"IMEINUMBER1":"911375058484548","LOGINPASSWORD":"12345"}
```

Comment: json is unordered ! Check [here](http://androiddhina.blogspot.in/2015/09/ordered-json-string-in-android.html)

Comment: Its working correct in Android Lollipop and marshmallow. But for below android version why its become unordered ?

Comment: You don't understood - you can't make things work over standards. `JSON` standard saying that JSON object is **an unordered set of name/value pairs** that  mean that reader should never depends on JSON fields ordering but rather access values by `name`. If you want to preserve order use JSON arrays instead: **An array is an ordered sequence of zero or more values.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `JSONObject` doesn't guarantee any order for its keys, it may sometimes be in the order of insertion, and sometimes not.

If you need to keep the order of insertion, use a [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) instead.