# How to write json Objects in order wise?Android

Tags: android, json

I am writing a `json` file to my external storage. Below code is used to create `json` objects and then adding them to `json` array

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

                jsonObj.put("slotid", "1a");
                jsonObj.put("updatetime", 1477650798);
                jsonObj.put("active", true);
                jsonObj.put("adurl", "httpAd");
                jsonObj.put("imgurl", "httpImg");
                jsonObj.put("hd", false);
                jsonObj.put("x", 0);
                jsonObj.put("y", 0);

                phoneArray.put(jsonObj);
                jsobObj.put("slots", phoneArray);
```

Above code works fine for `API24` but when i try to run same code for `API 19` then following output occurs

```
{
  "containers": [ ],
  "slots": [
    {
      "slotid": "1a",
      "updatetime": 1477650798,
      "adurl": "httpAd",
      "active": true,
      "hd": false,
      "y": 0,
      "x": 0,
      "imgurl": "httpImg"
    },
    {
      "slotid": "1a",
      "updatetime": 1477650798,
      "adurl": "httpAd",
      "active": true,
      "hd": false,
      "y": 0,
      "x": 0,
      "imgurl": "httpImg"
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is why my `jsonObjects` are not writing in order? I am successfully getting correct output on `API 24` i.e

```
{
  "slots": [
    {
      "slotid": "1a",
      "updatetime": 1477650798,
      "active": true,
      "adurl": "httpAd",
      "imgurl": "httpImg",
      "hd": "false",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    },
    {
      "slotid": "1a",
      "updatetime": 1477650798,
      "active": true,
      "adurl": "httpAd",
      "imgurl": "httpImg",
      "hd": "false",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    }
  ],
  "containers": []
}
```

Where should be the problem?

Comment: Whatever the ordering may be the working still remains same it will not be affected ...

Comment: I will try But why this is happening?

Comment: There may be various reasons I am not sure exactly ... may be the library first give importance to variables that have values and then variables that dont have any values in order to make easy for developers to look at.. I guess

Comment: but every variable has some value in it

Comment: May be as I said It was a guess the reason I made it was the containers array has zero objects in it and in second output it came after slots so...

Comment: yes but i have no issue with containers, the issue is that the json array i.e "slots" which contains json objects are not writing in order

Comment: May I know is there any problem that are you facing with it ?

Comment: I did not test it but i am actually ordered to do it that way

Comment: Ok ... that's fine let me know if you get any error

Comment: ok mate. one more question that can i break line after putting each json object into json array like above code i.e jsobObj.put("slots", phoneArray);? So that next next objects can be written on next line so that it is easy to view the code

Comment: No actually by default the JSON will try to save you space by removing unwanted space and again it will not affect the working .... but if you want them to have brakes there is a function called setPrettyPrinting() use that it will print with breaks...

Comment: JSONObject in API 19 and below uses HashMap where as from API 20 the same JSONObject uses LinkedHashMap (no official doc found but posts avaliable). There are many posts with similar questions in Stack Overflow for the same, i.e., check the below link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39346407/why-json-object-order-mixed-up-in-android-kitkat-and-below-versions, if really want different approach to attain the same see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515676/keep-the-order-of-the-json-keys-during-json-conversion-to-csv

Comment: I tested it, it works fine but my requirement is to arrange my JSONObjects in order :( what should i try

Comment: But why do you want them in order? You're not going to read the JSON obviously, you'll parse it using GSON/Moshi or anythinng else and that way, order of the elements doesn't matter.

Comment: yes you are right, i am getting all i want but i have got a job to do that and i have asked to order my jsonObjects in anyway. It sucks but i have to :(